# Best practice/place for data conversion

Tags: php, asp.net, jsp, coldfusion, data-conversion

I looked into but couldn't find succifient info.

> Where is to best place for data conversion including performance
>   consideration?In data query side or in web server side?

For instance:My database contains datetime fields and i am showing them in web page with different format.I can do it in database queries like:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, StartDate, 1)           --mssql
DATE_FORMAT(last_update, '%d/%m/%y')     -- mysql
TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yy');            -- oracle
```

or in web application codes:

```
date_format($date, 'd/m/y');                                     /*php*/
(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy")).parse(date)                   /*jsp*/
#DateFormat(date, 'dd/mm/yy')#                                   <!---coldfusion--->
date.ToString("dd/MM/yy")                                        //asp.net
```

of course in web codes date variable populated with date/time values without conversion in db queries. Also worth to mention that data extraction results have very much records.

**Note**:I am not professional with above platform/languages, wrote them to attract more answerers to generalize the question.Currently I am interested in cf/mssql.

Comment: I'd really love to know why the person voted to close this. It's "primarily opinion-based" possibly, but there are still real world, objective considerations which can be documented here.

Comment: What are the objective considerations? I'm very tempted to join that voter, or perhaps go with "too broad" - assuming it can be usefully answered (beyond "format data in the view"), then the question should either be made general (no lang tags), or completely language specific, but it's currently trying to be both. :/

Comment: @PeterBoughton, before opening this question i made some search and read many like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874016/what-is-the-best-practice-for-data-conversion-between-applications).But I saw that people judging about question and owner.First I tried to made it general,it got one vote to close, then i added specific tags(up to limit of five) then it had one more.Funny.How would i have to ask it?

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment on the performance side of things, although i would think it would be inconsequential either way.

From a "whose job is it to do the work" perspective, I see the need to format the date data in a human-friendly way is a UI conceit, not a data conceit (if you see what I mean), therefore the DB should just return a date, and it should be down to the CFML code - which is creating the web page - to format the date value in the way needed in the mark-up.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Adam.I am a big follower of your blogs about CFML.I wrote very different platforms including mobile and always wonder about best places of conversion/formatting thing.I usually thought in db it would be faster. Nice to learn different ideas.

Comment: It *might* be faster in the DB, but given it's such a simple operation, I don't think that's really a significant consideration compared to where it makes more sense to perform the work. Also, I don't think there's much in it either way. I don't think anyone would recoil in horror if they saw either approach, and their default position might be to do it the other way around. Cheers, btw, for the kind words about my blog. Glad someone's reading it!

Comment: There are other reasons to use application code instead of sql.  If the query is written in a stored procedure, it might be called by different apps with different formatting requirements.  Also, it the format depends on something, it's probably easier to code that logic in application code than sql.